# Difference between kappa and delta in mixed-effects model

Tags: model, spatio-temporal, mixed-model

I have a following stochastic model describing evolution of a process ($Y$) in space and time. Ds and Dt are domain in space (2D with $x$ and $y$ axes) and time (1D with $t$ axis). This model is usually known as [mixed-effects model](http://www.stat.missouri.edu/~wikle/ISR_hier_env_v2.pdf) or components-of-variation models

[image]

I am currently developing Y as follow:

```
%# Time parameters
T=1:1:20; % input
nT=numel(T);

%# Grid and model parameters
nRow=100;
nCol=100;


[Grid.Nx,Grid.Ny,Grid.Nt] = meshgrid(1:1:nCol,1:1:nRow,T);

xPower=0.1;
tPower=1;
noisePower=1;
detConstant=1;

deterministic_mu = detConstant.*(((Grid.Nt).^tPower)./((Grid.Nx).^xPower));

beta_s = randn(nRow,nCol); % mean-zero random effect representing location specific variability common to all times

gammaTemp = randn(nT,1);

for t = 1:nT
    gamma_t(:,:,t) = repmat(gammaTemp(t),nRow,nCol); % mean-zero random effect representing time specific variability common to all locations
end

var=0.1;% noise has variance = 0.1
for t=1:nT
    kappa_st(:,:,t) = sqrt(var)*randn(nRow,nCol);
end

for t=1:nT
    Y(:,:,t) = deterministic_mu(:,:,t) + beta_s + gamma_t(:,:,t) + kappa_st(:,:,t);
end
```

Can someone help explain, through some illustration using Matlab, if I am correctly producing $Y$? Also, how to produce delta in the expression for $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but it seems that the delta is iid noise, like an ordinary residual, and kappa is likely to be correlated over space and time.  In terms of parameters, delta would just have one (variance), and kappa would have at least two (variance + correlation).